# Calling ServiceBus' IQueueClient.CompleteAsync() from a different thread always fails

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, hangfire

I'm receiving from a queue using `IQueueClient.RegisterMessageHandler()`, and in the receiving method I'm then starting a Hangfire task. But in the Hangfire task, all calls to `IQueueClient.CompleteAsync()` to mark the message as consumed (because I'm using `ReceiveMode.PeekLock` mode) fail.

I suspect it's because the Hangfire task re-creates the `IQueueClient`, that it may be because the call to `CompleteAsync()` is from a different instance of `IQueueClient`? Or is something else possibly going wrong? I'm passing `Message.SystemProperties.LockToken` into the Hangfire task which is what is then being used by `CompleteAsync`.

Comment: You should provide the exception when asking to help with a failing code. Usually, the stack trace or the error message has the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I suspect it's because the Hangfire task re-creates the IQueueClient, that it may be because the call to CompleteAsync() is from a different instance of IQueueClient?

That's correct. `LockToken` is not enough to complete the message. You have to use the same client used to receive the message in order to complete it.